# Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\LOCAL SERVICE'. error after data creation or edit

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-core

I'm implementing asp.net core 3.1 project and using sql server 2014. My app has got 4 controllers each of which has create, edit and delete actions. All of 3 controllers except one of them works fine whereas when I create or edit via the problematic controller, an error like the following is being shown to me:

An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the reques:

> Exception:  Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Login
> failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\LOCAL SERVICE'.    at
> Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity
> identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential
> credential, Object providerInfo, String newPassword, SecureString
> newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString
> userConnectionOptions, SessionData reconnectSessionData, Boolean
> applyTransientFaultHandling, String accessToken, DbConnectionPool
> pool, SqlAuthenticationProviderManager sqlAuthProviderManager) ....

As I mentioned. all of the controllers except one of them has the above error for its actions. That controller is using 3 tables and one of them has one to many relationship with two others and those tables which are at many point have got acomputed column specification with the
`(isnull(CONVERT([int],(2)),(15)))` formula.
I appreciate if anyone can suggests me a solution.

Comment: I suggest to use SQL Profiler to capture the SQL statement and related exception that causes this issue.

Comment: I advice you to allow `NT AUTHORITY\LOCAL SERVICE` to server Role as `sysadmin`, you can have a reference for: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28721645/12884742

Answer (score 0):

The problem could be in Sql Connection Strings and IIS Application Pool, what are these for your asp.net core application.

[SqlException: Login failed for user 'DOMAIN\MACHINENAME$' for SQL Server with .NET Core 2.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59275810/sqlexception-login-failed-for-user-domain-machinename-for-sql-server-with-n?rq=1)

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/connection-strings
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/iis/?view=aspnetcore-3.1